# How to open the filemanager in a specific folder using Opencart?

Tags: ajax, opencart

I am creating a multi-seller in my ecommerce and I want to have a folder in every seller.

So I need to have a directory like this.

```
catalog/
  image/
    seller/
      1/
        /profile
        /banner
        /products
      2/
        /profile
        /banner
        /products
```

Where 1 and 2 is represented as a seller ID. In the Opencart default setup it always landed on the root folder of the image.

How can I control the directory? And also how can I prevent the filemanager from going back to the root directory?

Where should I edit those parts?

Usually the filemanager is in this code.

```
<a href="" id="thumb-image<?php echo $image_row; ?>" data-toggle="image" class="img-thumbnail">
    <img src="<?php echo $product_image['thumb']; ?>" alt="" title="" data-placeholder="<?php echo $placeholder; ?>" />
</a>
```

I am using **Opencart Version 2.0.1.1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a directory as in the query string as `directory=example` in the ajax call.  The url itself is specified in `admin/view/javascript/common.js`.  You will need to amend the code here to capture the logged in user's id and use it to specify a path.  Something like this:

```
url: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager&token=' + getURLVar('token') + '&target=' + $(element).parent().find('input').attr('id') + '&thumb=' + $(element).attr('id') + '&directory=<?php $this->user->getId(); ?>',
```